# When I add a theme to my ggplot, it ignores my changes made to the x axis, how do i stop this happening?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I have created a line graph but I want to add a theme to make it look more visually pleasing. In the original graph, I have plotted the x labels to the side so they are readable and dont overlap. however,when i add a theme, R seems to ignore these changes and it reverts them back. Is there a way to still add the theme and keep my changes made to the x axis?

the data:

```
structure(list(day = structure(c(19210, 19210, 19211, 19211, 
19212, 19212, 19213, 19213, 19214, 19214, 19215, 19215, 19216, 
19216, 19217, 19217, 19218, 19218, 19219, 19221, 19222, 19223, 
19223, 19224, 19225, 19226, 19226, 19227, 19227, 19228, 19228, 
19229, 19229, 19230, 19231, 19231, 19232, 19232, 19238, 19238, 
19239, 19239, 19240, 19241, 19242, 19242, 19243), class = "Date"), 
    trialtype = c("go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", 
    "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", 
    "go", "nogo", "go", "go", "go", "go", "nogo", "go", "go", 
    "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", 
    "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", 
    "go", "go", "nogo", "go"), mean = c(0.496695906432749, 0.54765, 
    0.44894269005848, 0.406666666666667, 0.444126315789474, 0.3496, 
    0.442609356725146, 0.4528, 0.462447953216374, 0.4262, 0.47875730994152, 
    0.464266666666667, 0.459146783625731, 0.261666666666667, 
    0.479398830409357, 0.4199, 0.48975730994152, 0.2944, 0.511256140350877, 
    0.49047485380117, 0.543529239766082, 0.513159064327485, 0.5597, 
    0.51296783625731, 0.478275438596491, 0.492419298245614, 0.1061, 
    0.49356432748538, 0.4948, 0.534784795321637, 0.5097, 0.509980701754386, 
    0.2998, 0.505461988304094, 0.52029649122807, 0.52315, 0.52303216374269, 
    0.5337, 0.517447368421053, 0.3997, 0.517894152046784, 0.696366666666667, 
    0.511729824561403, 0.5346, 0.515273684210526, 0.508, 0.552337426900585
    )), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -47L), groups = structure(list(day = structure(c(19210, 
19211, 19212, 19213, 19214, 19215, 19216, 19217, 19218, 19219, 
19221, 19222, 19223, 19224, 19225, 19226, 19227, 19228, 19229, 
19230, 19231, 19232, 19238, 19239, 19240, 19241, 19242, 19243
), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 
    9:10, 11:12, 13:14, 15:16, 17:18, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22:23, 24L, 
    25L, 26:27, 28:29, 30:31, 32:33, 34L, 35:36, 37:38, 39:40, 
    41:42, 43L, 44L, 45:46, 47L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -28L), .drop = TRUE))
```

my code for the ggplot:

```
p7 <- p07_dropped_rt %>% 
  group_by(trialtype) %>% 
  arrange(day) %>% 
  mutate(days = paste0("day",row_number())) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_inorder(days), y = mean, group = trialtype)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = trialtype, linetype = trialtype)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('green','red')) +
  geom_point(aes(color = trialtype, shape = trialtype)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(title=" P07s Average response time of Go/No-go Trials",
       x = "Day of training",
       y = "Average Response Time (s) ",
       color = "Trial Type") 


p7
```

I have attached the images with and without a theme for reference

[image]
[image]

thank you :)

Comment: You need to add the theme **before** you use `theme()`. For example: `+ theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 0.5))`